# Intuition explanation: Dedekind cuts

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I understand the intuition behind the construction of the reals using Dedekind cuts. However, I struggle to understand why Dedekind chose the term closed downwards. If I am imagining a partition $(A,B)$ of $\mathbb{R}$,in my understanding the set $A$ would form the "lower half/left half" on the real number line (colored red in linked example below). Is that correct? If yes, why did he choose the term closed downwards ? My knowledge of topology is quite limited but I would say that since it is an open interval  to the left, open downwards would be a more appropriate term. Is there something I am misunderstanding here?

For reference, the explanation I am looking at is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_by_Dedekind_cuts) one.

Comment: "closed" not in the topological sense (no topology at that time) but in the sense of "no hole": r is closed downwards. In other words, for all $x,y\in \textbf {Q} \text { such that } x<y, \text { if } y\in r \text { then } x\in r$.

Comment: I think of it as "[closed under the operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) of going downward". i.e., for any element $x\in A$, if $y<x$, then $y\in A$.

Comment: I don't think you shouldn't blame Dedekind for terminology that some Wikipedia editor has chosen to use more than a century later and in a different language... In his original work, he simply talks about a partition (*Zerlegung*) of the set of rationals into two subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that every member of $A_1$ is less than every member of $A_2$.